# Wrong title for Beta badge

Tags: bug, status-completed

The [badges page](https://money.stackexchange.com/badges) says that the Beta badge is for people who participated in the **Stack Overflow** beta. Other StackExchange sites don't seem to have this problem (see [diy](https://diy.stackexchange.com/badges) or [ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/badges)), so I don't know if it's on this end (doesn't look like you can [edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139/are-the-badge-names-editable) the badge name) or just a strange bug on SE.

Comment: It seems to have been fixed.  It's generic now.